# Viewpager2 open selected page (from cardview) without fragment

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, android-viewpager2

Quick question here. I have a cardview, and a viewpager2. Is it possible to open a selected page of the viewpager, in function of the item I clicked on the cardview, but without fragment ?
I think I should use `getCount()` in order to select which page I want to display, but how can I link it to the cardview adapter? (which I have the positions of items).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at ViewPager2 [setCurrentItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setCurrentItem(int))

Comment: Thank you, after several tests I finally manage to transfer my position from an activity to another, and select the current view with `setCurrentItem`. Do you know how to delete the little "sliding animation" which takes place when the viewpager is opening, going from page X to the page with the selected position ?

Comment: This [setCurrentItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)) can help, pass false

Comment: Oh thx didn't paid attention to this one . Thank you for your help, have a good day !

Comment: Added you as an answer, I'll accept it when I can !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the current item of `Viewpager2` you can use the [setCurrentItem (int item)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setCurrentItem(int)) or the [setCurrentItem (int item,
boolean smoothScroll)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)).

The second allows you to pass a boolean value to indicate whether to animate smoothly when changing the pages.